# É possível colocar o conteúdo de um "objeto de thymeleaf" dentro de uma "variável", em HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

**Para contextualizar:**

Possuo um objeto "log", que foi declarado em uma pagina HTML através do thymeleaf:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:include="layout :: page">
  ...
 <form class="form-inline" action="#" th:action="@{'log/'}" th:object="${log}" method="post">
```

Em certa parte do código é exibido o conteúdo desse objeto, que nada mais é que um "stringão" de texto:

```
<p th:utext="${log.content}">Log content</p>
```

Conteúdo:

```
1. a
2. b
3. c
...
```

**Minha duvida:**

É possível colocar esse conteúdo dentro de uma variável, para então usar dentro de um .js?

Algo como:

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" th:value="${log.content}" >
```

Js:

```
var aux = $('input');
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = aux.value;
```

Meu objetivo é poder manusear esse "`log.content`" fora do HTML, é possível?

Comment: Vc quer pegar o valor do input hidden é isto?

Comment: Isso, eu quero colocar o ${log.content} dentro de alguma variável e utiliza-lo. Utilizei o <input> só como exemplo, mas já serviria também!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dentro deste `input` vai ter um valor trazido pelo **th:value="${log.content}"**. Você pode pegar o valor de diversas formas, por **id**, por **classe**, normalmente com *Javascript* ou *jQuery*:

```js
var valorInput1 = $('input:hidden').val(); // jQuery
console.log(valorInput1);                 // pega o valor do input que está com display none

var valorInput2 = document.getElementById('valorDoInput').value; // Javascript
console.log(valorInput2); // pega o valor do input com um id
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="hidden" th:value="${log.content}" value="10">

<input type="hidden" id="valorDoInput" th:value="${log.content}" value="20">
```